# rewrite help doing redirect rather Proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Need help on below rewrite rule. It's keep redirecting rather proxy

```
RewriteRule ^/corenet/life(/?|.html)$ /contentsite/sites12/corenet/life.html  [P,L]
```

- > GET /corenet/life.html HTTP/1.1
  >   User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
  >   Host: www-stage.sitesx.com
  >   Accept: */*
  >
  > < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  >      < Date: Thu, 24 Aug 2017 13:55:51 GMT
  >      < Server: Apache
  >      < Location: https://www-stage.sitex.com/contentsite/sites12/corenet/life.html
  >      < Content-Length: 0

Comment: the substitution must contain `http://domain/..`

Comment: That redirect you receive is not caused by the above RewriteRule

Comment: Issue is fixed. Actually this is a node behind f5 loadbalancer with HTTPS Redirect. www-stage-sitex.com IP's is Load Balanced IP (VIP).  When Node does reverse proxy to http://www-stage.sitex.com/contentsite/sites12/corenet/life.html request reached to F5 LB that send 302 for https. To fix i have updated /etc/hosts of node F5's-VIP-IP   www-stage-sitex.com. After it works !

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed. Actually this is a node behind f5 loadbalancer with HTTPS Redirect. www-stage.sitex.com IP's is Load Balanced IP ( F5 VIP). When Node does reverse proxy to www-stage.sitex.com/contentsite/sites12/corenet/life.html request reaches to F5 LB that send 302 for https. To fix i have updated /etc/hosts of node F5's-VIP-IP www-stage-sitex.com. After it works !